# Set difference in MySQL without primary key

Tags: mysql, sql, set-difference

I want to do an EXCEPT/MINUS in MySQL. If primary keys were available, the obvious solution would be:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table_a AS a
WHERE
    a.ID not in(
        SELECT
            b.ID
        FROM
            table_b AS b
    )
```

However, what if I don't have a key column and I want an actual set difference, i.e. taking into account all (possibly many) columns?

I want something like

```
SELECT * FROM table_a WHERE * NOT IN …
```

This isn't possible of course. I can't assign an entire row to a variable, can I? Any ideas?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can still use `not in`:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where (a.col1, a.col2, . . . ) not in (select b.col1, b.col2, . . . from table_b b);
```

I would tend to use `exists`, however:

```
select a.*
from table_a a
where not exists (select 1
                  from table_b b
                  where a.col1 = b.col1 and a.col2 = b.col2 and . . .
                 );
```

`Not exists` usually works more intuitively if any columns have `null`.  Plus, you can use `<=>`, the `NULL`-safe equality operator.